# "No suitable display mode found" error for Dawn of War & DoW: Winter Assault

Tags: technical-issues, backwards-compatibility, warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

This is in conjunction with my [other problem with compatibility issues with this game and Windows 8.1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161636/warhammer-40k-pc-game-not-playing-on-windows-8-1/): I dummied the driver to allow my graphics card which worked for *Dark Crusade*).

But on the earlier games stated in the title, it succeeded only in getting to the configuration stage where (after selecting my graphics card) it states:

> No suitable display modes were found

**Background:**

I recently upgraded my computer to a Windows 8.1 HP Envy. The games installed fine. However when I tried to run the game it failed with the 'Spooge Driver' error message in my [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161636/warhammer-40k-pc-game-not-playing-on-windows-8-1/). (*Dawn of War*, *DoW: Winter Assault* and *DoW: Dark Crusade*) all gave the same error.

This is now fixed for *Dark Crusade* but did not work for the first two. The fix was an edit to the Driver folder in the Direct X directory in the Dawn of War files

I have tried running in Compatibility Mode (XP) to no avail.

So, what can I do to get a 'suitable display mode' and stop Windows 8.1 throwing that error?

Quick computer Specs:

Graphics card Nvidia Geforce GTX 760 (192-bit)

16 GB RAM

Beats Audio

Brief Update - I have Upgraded to Windows 10 and all the compatibility options wont work.

Comment: Have you tried using compatibility mode? I hear that will work wonders. If you've gone to the point of editing drivers, have you modified the video modes to be able to display the same modes? (I know how to do this in linux but not windows.)

Comment: the way my driver fixed works is there is a list of compatible cards in the direct x driver root files that allow the program to run on it, I simply have an updated list that includes my graphics card in the code what you mentioned may be of great use I'll have a look into that.

Comment: @NathanTaylor - Hey, I've linked the previous question to this one. Did you dummy out the drivers.txt (as in, left it blank) or did you add the contents that I gave in the previous answer?

Comment: if the latter, its possible your graphics card wasn't in the list, in which case we may have to try making an entry for the file manually.

Comment: I added the contents and it worked for Dark crusade but not 1 and winter assault

Comment: @Robotnik btw that edit to the question is much appreciated its worded a lot better now I need to work on my information relaying skills... as an IT tech its pretty shameful haha

Comment: No worries man. It wasn't too bad, the big thing I find on Arqade  is the title - if you want the question to be noticed you've gotta have a descriptive title. Anyway, I'm trying to research a bit more about this driver/graphics card thing. Could you add your Graphics card + the version of Dawn of War/Winter Assault please? I'm about to leave for home so I'll be able to research a bit more once I'm there.

Comment: Ahh see I'm at work myself I'll need to wait till I get home in 7 hours :/

Comment: Fair enough well I'll do my best :)

Comment: @Robotnik i have added my graphics card along with a few additional specs hope it helps

Comment: @NathanTaylor - Hey sorry, I couldn't find much new, and then I got really sick over the past couple of days. That graphics card seems fairly new, it's likely it wasn't included in the config. I've grabbed my copy of the [spdx9_config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48802429/spdx9_config.txt) file - can you see if it works with it?

Comment: Oh I hope your feeling better, I tried the new text file and nothing changed :/

Comment: @Robotnik Could it have something to do with the disk because it has to run from the disk itself there could be compatibility issues with the drivers on the disk?

Comment: I don't think so, it should try and run whatever's in the install directory or installed on the PC. I'm sorry I honestly cannot tell you what is going on this time :/

Comment: Are these the Steam versions?

Comment: @Burgi No they are the disk versions

Comment: "I simply have an updated list that includes my graphics card in the code" Ever wondered why they  made a list? That's because not every graphics card can handle the version of directX they used for the game (things used to be that way, you literally had to look up if your specific GPU could handle the game's version of directX). Yours isn't in there because it didn't exist when they made the game, so it could work just fine, but chances are it just doesn't have the full implementation for the version of directX the game uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a Link on Steam that answers my question perfectly:

> Own Boxed Copies of DoW? Get Free Steam Keys
>
> With the shutting of Gamespy servers, we have been migrating our
>   players over to Steam.
>
> However if you purchased box versions of the game and do not own the
>   game on Steam, you do not need to re-purchase the games.We are
>   supplying owners of boxed copies with free steam keys so you can
>   continue to enjoy the DoW franchise without paying again.
>
> You can request your steam keys by filing a ticket through the
>   following page:
>
> https://support.sega.co.uk/hc/requests/new
>
> Please note that Sega will need to verify your boxed copies, this may
>   involve them requesting photos of your box or other information. Due
>   to the volume of requests it may also take a few days for them to
>   reply - we apologize this and thank the community for it's patience.
>
> We did not want to see DoW end with the closure of the Gamespy
>   servers, and are happy to see that our players are still quite
>   passionate!

[Here is the original Link to the steam community Forum.](http://steamcommunity.com/app/4570/discussions/0/535150948618039156/)

So as I have the boxed versions of the games with the license keys I will be able to request a new installer.

thanks for all of your help on this issue. Its much appreciated!